# postgres Join 2 cols into 1

Tags: postgresql

Want to join lat lon into 1. How is this done without the () in the results?

```
select name, (lat, lng)  as coords from my_table
```

But this prints:

```
name      coords    
a         (,)    
b         ( 122, 333)
```

I need:

```
name     coords    
a        122, 333
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need?

```
select name, lat|| ', ' || lng as coords from my_table
```